# Is is possible to use the @keyword decorator more than once on a python method for use in the robot framework

Tags: python-2.7, robotframework

Is it possible to set more than 1 @keyword decorator on an external python library for use in the robotframework
e.g.

```
from robot.api.deco import keyword
class TestLib:

    @keyword(name = 'Keyword1 check ${expected_data}')
    @keyword(name = 'This is keyword2 ${expected_data}')
    def check_returns_expected_data(self, expected_data):
        '''
        :param expected_data: string
        '''
        print expected_data
```

Comment: Have you tried it? Did it work?

Comment: I did and it didn't. I was hoping I had missed something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot call it twice. Or more correctly, you can call it twice but you still end up with a single keyword. This decorator doesn't create keywords, it merely sets metadata on the function being decorated.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
from robot.api.deco import keyword
class TestLib:

    @keyword(name = 'Keyword1 check ${expected_data}')
    def check_returns_expected_data1(self, expected_data):
        self._check_returns_expected_data(expected_data)

    @keyword(name = 'This is keyword2 ${expected_data}')
    def check_returns_expected_data2(self, expected_data):
        self._check_returns_expected_data(expected_data)

    def _check_returns_expected_data(self, expected_data):
        '''
        :param expected_data: string
        '''
        print expected_data
```